# Die reliably in response to a signal

Tags: perl, try-catch, signals

The following code is supposed to time out after a certain period, due to arrival of SIGALRM -

```
sub sig_alrm_handler() { die "Timed out, sorry" }

$SIG{ALRM} = \&sig_alrm_handler;
main();
```

Usually this approach works, except sometimes main() includes a Try::Tiny 'try' block which intercepts the "die" from sig_alrm_handler, effectively ignoring the timeout.  How can this approach be changed so that SIGALRM will reliably terminate the program, even when main() catches exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to end your program, you can call [exit](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html) from your signal function. If you have an [END](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END) block, it will still execute that.

Here's a code example. I used `SIGINT` for it, but `SIGALRM` works the same way.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Try::Tiny;

sub sig_int_handler() {
#   die "Dying from SIGINT\n";
    warn "Exiting from SIGINT\n";
    exit(128 | 2);   # 2 = SIGINT
};

$SIG{INT} = \&sig_int_handler;
my $i = 0;
try {
    while (1) {

    }
} catch {
    print "caught exception\n";
};

print "continuing execution\n";
```

In this example, if you hit `ctrl-c` while it is running, it will exit without printing the two `print` statements. However if you uncomment the line with `die` on it in the `sig_int_handler` subroutine, it will print them both when you send the `INT` signal.